# React SPFx - Adding files to SharePoint list field using PnPjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, web-applications, spfx

I'm building an application using SPFx Webpart with React. On one of my components I have a form that the user can fill out. I'm using PnPjs to push the user's responses into my list field. Everything works as expected.

I was looking at how to add a file or attachment field type to a list. I saw I can do it in the powerapps. So now in my "Product" list I have a field called `attachments`. When I attach files to that field from SharePoint's backend and then make a call to the list using `PnPjs` the attachment field does not return information about the files. But rather a `boolean` with a true or false.

```
pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Products").items.filter("Id eq '" + this.props.match.params.id + "'").top(1).get().then((items: any[]) => {
    console.log(items); 
}
```

So this works perfect and returns back the item which should have had the attachments from the code below. Now in my `items` console I get back `Attachments: true` or `Attachments: false`

I'm using `react-dropzone` to allow users to upload files. Using `PnPjs` how do I upload the files to that item?

Here is how I'm creating the item:

```
pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Requests").items.add({
    Title: this.state.SuggestedVendor,
    Client_x0020_Email: this.state.getEmail,
    Created: this.state.startDate,
    Attachments: //need help here
}
```

Here is my code for the dropdown files:

```
onDrop = (acceptedFiles) => {
   console.log(acceptedFiles);
   //Assuming this is where I do the logic
}

<Dropzone 
    onDrop={this.onDrop}
    multiple
    >
    {({getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive}) => (
        <div {...getRootProps()}>
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
        {isDragActive ? "Drop it like it's hot!" : 'Click me or drag a file to upload!'}
        </div>
    )}
</Dropzone>
```

And here is the response I get back from `console.log(acceptedFiles);`:

```
[File]
0: File {path: "John-Hancock-signature.png", name: "John-Hancock-signature.png", lastModified: 1590783703732, lastModifiedDate: Fri May 29 2020 13:21:43 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time), webkitRelativePath: "", …}
length: 1
```

I found this documentation here on how to push the files : https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/files/

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the item, and then add an attachment to it.

> You can add an attachment to a list item using the add method. This method takes either a string, Blob, or ArrayBuffer. [pnp documentation](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/attachments/#add-an-attachment)

```js
onDrop = (acceptedFiles) => {
    acceptedFiles.forEach(file => {

        const reader = new FileReader()

        reader.onabort = () => console.log('file reading was aborted')
        reader.onerror = () => console.log('file reading has failed')
        reader.onload = async () => {
            // get file content
            const binaryStr = reader.result

            // assume we have itemId
            let itemId = 1;
            let request = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Requests").items.getById(itemId)();
            await request.attachmentFiles.add("file2.txt", "Here is my content");
        }
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
    })



}
```